# How to genercize a function such that it accepts any Container?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I would like to do something like this

```
template <typename> 
void (T arg){
   
}
```

Such that I could pass in any container, like vector or list, but not any type that isn't a container. How would I achieve this? Is this not possible?

Comment: Use iterators.  Most all containers have iterators and the contents can be accessed by dereferencing the iterator.

Comment: @Shisui : There is a good C++20 solution for this, but unfortunately there is no good C++17 solution.

Answer (score -2):

Use a **template template parameter**, eg:

```
template <template<class...> class Container, class... Args>
void func(const Container<Args...> &arg)
{
    ...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/jq2mio)